# Validate x-api-key in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Hello!**

My infrastructure:

The request arrives to the AWS API Gateway and the gateway forwards it to the lambda.
The x-api-key in my case can be found only in the body of the request (no way to change this).

**The question is:**
How can I validate x-api-key in the lambda function?

Comment: Do you not have API Gateway validate it?  That's the whole point of it so that your Lambda doesn't get called unless the key is correct.

Comment: The problem is that the service I'm trying to integrate is legacy. (We can't change it) and api key can be sent only in the body.

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood before.  I see three ways (1) create a model in API gateway for the body and have API gateway validate or (2) create an authorizer Lambda for API gateway and have it read the body to validate the token or (3) have the end Lambda read the body to validate the token.  Are you having problems reading the body in the Lambda?  If so, can you show the code where you try to read it?